# A simple jquery change() is not working on safari

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to set the dropdown option by using a simple jquery code:

```
$('option[value="1"]').attr('selected', 'selected').change();
```

and its working fine on Chrome and Firefox but not on Safari.

Anyone, please help in solving this strange issue. Thanks in advance.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#btn').click(function(){
    $('option[value="1"]').attr('selected', 'selected');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="dd">
   <option value="">Select</option>
   <option value="1">One</option>
   <option value="2">Two</option>
   <option value="3">Three</option>
 </select>

 <input type="button" value="click me" id="btn" />
```

Comment: Events are not supported cross on `<option>` tag. You will have the same issue in IE also and potentially other browsers

Comment: You haven't `change`d the option's `value`, **so no change to report.** The only `value` that changed is `dd.value`.

Comment: @connexo you can still trigger a change event even  when value hasn't changed. By doing it on `<option>` I think OP was counting on it bubbling

Comment: @charlietfl Ofc you can, but it's pointless if the `value` of the element `change` is dispatched on hasn't changed at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Events are not supported cross browser on `<option>` tag. You will have the same issue in IE also and potentially other browsers. The same is true of trying to hide `<option>`

Set the value of the `<select>` and trigger change on that

```js
$('#btn').click(function() {
  $('#dd').val('1').change();
});

$('select').change(function() {
  console.log(`Select #${this.id} was changed to ${this.value}`)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="dd">
  <option value="">Select</option>
  <option value="1">One</option>
  <option value="2">Two</option>
  <option value="3">Three</option>
</select>

<input type="button" value="click me" id="btn" />
```